# fetching records against comma separated values from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php in my web site. Here i want to fetch a record in such a way that match against a comma separated values. Please read below example
 I have two tables.

1. Table 1 say user, which have a  column name say `itemcode`

   eg:

   `id = 1 itemcode =3,10`
2. Table 2 say itemsList, which al so have itemcode field

   eg :

   ```
   id=1 itemcode= 1,3,7,5,
   id=2   itemcode= 4,9,10
   id=3 itemcode= 1,3,10,11
   id=4 itemcode 2,3,7,10
   id=5 itemcode 1,2,8,9
   ```

I need to display all the records from itemsList table which have itemcode `3 or 10`

ie need to display the records with ids = 1, 2,3,4

Comment: **DO NOT** store comma-separated values in the database.

Comment: You can use FIND_IN_SET (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), but normalising your database is better; especially as you'll have to use it twice in this case (once for each of the two values you want)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE
  FIND_IN_SET(3, itemcode) OR
  FIND_IN_SET(10, itemcode)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62b3f/1).